# Reset Fieldset values to null - Apex

Tags: apex, fieldsets

How do I reset fieldset values to null.
I have fieldsets used in search criteria and I want to reset them.
I do not want all values of the Object to be reset,but only fieldset values should be reset.
Sample code which I'm currently using in code for filter criteria:

```
for(Schema.FieldSetMember canFilter : getCanFilters()){

          if(canFilter.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.String){
            query += ' and '+ canFilter.getFieldPath()+ '=\''+ String.valueOf(con.get(canFilter.getFieldPath()))+'\'';
}
```

Now, I want `String.valueOf(con.get(canFilter.getFieldPath()))` to null on some reset event/click.

Thank you for any Help!

Comment: didn't understand completely, can you elaborate

Comment: Well, in fieldset we have field API and by using instance of object , we get values of that field. Here I'm doing thing i.e assigning value of the field in Query filter against same field. Now I want that instance fields which has some values while using in query to be reset to null.

Comment: If you do not want to add a filter for empty fields, just skip it from where clause?